# C++ Dynamically convert string to any basic type

Tags: c++, xml, string, parsing

In C++ I need to convert a string to any type at runtime where I do not know what type I might be getting in the string.  I have heard there is a lexical_cast in boost that I can use, but what would be the most effective way to implement it?

I might get a bunch of string like this from a client: Date="25/08/2010", Someval="2", Blah="25.5".

Now I want to be able to convert these strings to their type, eg, the Somval is obviously an int, and the Date could be a boost::date or whatever.  The point is, I don't know at this time in what order these would be given to me, so it's hard to write some code that will perform a bunch of casts.

I could use a bunch of if/else statements or a switch/case statements, however I'm thinking that there is possibly a better way to do this.

I'm not looking for something different to lexical_cast, I can totally use that, I am looking to see if someone knows a better way then doing this:

```
std::string str = "256";
int a = lexical_cast<int>(str);

//now check if the cast worked, if not, try another...
```

This is too much of a guessing game, and if I have 10 possible types, for any given string, it sounds a bit ineffective.  Especially if it has to do 1000's of these at any given time.

Can anybody advice?

---

*Alex Brown* notes - the example string is a fragment of the XML data that comes from the client.

Comment: [As usual](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html): **Why?**

Comment: @GMan: what do you mean why? Do you not understand the question or do you want a reason for me trying to do this?

Comment: @Tony Read the link. :) Ask about the goal, not the step. You, as the person asking a question because you cannot solve the problem, are the last person to know what steps you need to take. So don't; ask the goal. In any case, types are determined at compile time. You cannot "cast" a string to a type, that doesn't make sense. (Not anymore than you can cast an int to a namespace.) What you can do is have a map of strings to function pointers, and call the function pointer corresponding to that "type" (string). Of course, it's impossible to give you a real answer until we get a real question. :)

Comment: If you have the string "235", I'm sure you can cast it to an int, or if you have a string "25/05/2005", I'm sure you can convert it to some Date type, etc... what I want to know is how that can be done?

Comment: @Tony: read GMan's link. There are probably a billion solutions, most of which are inappropriate for you. We're not going to guess.

Comment: @Tony: Is there some reason you feel the need for something other than lexical_cast? What are your criteria for deciding what kind of solution is the most effective?

Comment: What do you want to DO with these values once they have been collected?

Comment: @Alex: I need to be able to perform math operations on them, and since math operations on strings are a bit hard, I need to convert them

Comment: @Tony: use the words with their correct meaning: you don't want to cast a string to any other type, but rather *convert* from the string to its equivalent value in other types if possible. It is important to be precise when dealing with technical issues.

Comment: How do multiple values relate to each other?  Will you be storing them in a struct?  are there multiple records?  what format is the source data - XML? YAML? HTML? some other format?

Comment: @Alex, the source is XML, its just a request from a client, where the node name is the request type, and the attributes the values needed to do the calculations for the request

Comment: Are you using an XML parser? If not, why not?  I think you will get better results, and the parser will do a lot of the legwork for you - and avoid the ordering issues.

Comment: This is exactly the reason why @Gman posted the link in the first comment. It has taken a total of 11 comments to get to know what the real problem to solve is (which by the way, renders my answer invalid). People is willing to help, but the **very least** that you can do is provide the information so that their time is not lost. That is just showing **respect** for other's time.

Answer (score 2):

Use an XML parser to read XML data, it will do almost all of the legwork for you, and deal with the ordering issues.  Then you simply need to ask the parser for the data you need for the calculation.

Details differ with different XML parsers - go find one, read the documentation.  If you need more help, come back here with an XML parser question.

Answer (score 0):

GMan is right, you can not cast an arbitrary string to for example a Date type if the underlaying data structure is different. You can, however, parse the content and instantiate a new object using the data in the string. std::atoi() parses a c-string to an int for example.
You need to parse the string, not cast it.

Comment: He probably means *convert* rather than *cast*.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a `VARIANT` type of struct (i.e. one of every possible results, and a "type" specifying which it was, and a big enum of types), and a `ConvertStringToVariant()` function.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is actually a parser. Even the trial-and-error approach using `lexical_cast` is really just a (crude) parser.

I suggest to clarify the format of the input string and then, if it's simple enough, write a [Recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) by hand to parse the input string into whatever data structure is convenient for your need.

Answer (score 0):

> This is too much of a guessing game,
>   and if I have 10 possible types, for
>   any given string

If you're concerned about this, you need a lexical analyzer, such as [flex](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/c/software/flex/flex.html#SEC5) or [Boost::Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/).

It will still be a guessing game, but a more "informed" guessing one.